# C++ operator overloading input operator >> with object outside class as member

Tags: c++, input, operator-overloading

This is homework--I am having issues defining my input >> operator overload for my Customer.h file, where an object from another class is a member of this class.  I will be using the input operator to read data in from a text file and output it to a BinaryTree.  We have a Customer class and an Address class.  Address is a member of Customer (part of Customer's constructor).  I have to read in the file which contains:
CustomerID
CustomerName
AddressStreet
AddressCity
AddressZip

Customer's constructor is Customer(int custID, string custName, Address* address) so I'm having problems with my input overload in the Customer class, where I have to read in the address data as the street, city, state, zip but store it as the Customer address.  I may have done something wrong with my class declarations, too.  Here is what I have:

Customer.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Address.h"

using namespace std;

class Customer
{
private:
//Attributes for customers
int custID;
string custName;
Address* address;

public:
//Constructors for Customer
Customer();
Customer(int, string, Address*);
~Customer();
//Setters for Customer
void setCustID(int);
void setCustName(string);
void setCustAddress(Address*);
//Getters for Customer
int getCustID() {return custID;}
string getCustName() {return custName;}

//Operator overloads
bool operator>(Customer obj) {return custID > obj.custID;}
bool operator<(Customer obj) {return custID < obj.custID;}
bool operator==(Customer obj) {return custID == obj.custID;}

//Operator overloads for input
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Customer &customer) {
    input >> customer.custID >> customer.custName >> /*?????  Here's where I can't figure out what to call for the address street, city, state, zip; */ << endl;
    return input;
}

//Operator overloads for output
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Customer &customer) {
    output << "CustID: " << customer.custID << endl << "Customer Name: " << customer.custName << endl << "Customer Address: " << customer.address << endl;
    return output;
}

};
```

Customer.cpp:

```
#include "Customer.h"

//Customer no arg constructor
Customer::Customer()
{
custID = 0;
custName = "";
}

//Customer constructor
Customer::Customer(int custID, string custName, Address* address)
{
this->custID = custID;
this->custName = custName;
this->address = address;
}

//Customer destructor
Customer::~Customer()
{

}
```

Address.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Address 
{
private:
string street;
string city;
string state;
string zip;

public:
//Constructors for address
Address();
Address(string, string, string, string);
~Address();
//Setters for address
void setAddressStreet(string);
void setAddressCity(string);
void setAddressState(string);
void setAddressZip(string);
//Getters for address
string getAddressStreet() {return street;}
string getAddressCity() {return city;}
string getAddressState() {return state;}
string getAddressZip() {return zip;}

//Operator overload for input
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Address &address) {
    input >> address.street >> address.city >> address.state >> address.zip;
    return input;
}
//Operator overload for output
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Address &address) {
    output << "Street: " << address.street << endl << "City: " << address.city << endl << "State: " << address.state << endl << "Zip: " << address.zip << endl;
    return output;
}
};
```

Address.cpp:

```
#include "Address.h"

//Address no arg constructor
Address::Address()
{
street = "";
city = "";
state = "";
zip = "";
}

//Address constructor
Address::Address(string street, string city, string state, string zip)
{
this->street = street;
this->city = city;
this->state = state;
this->zip = zip;
}

//Address destructor
Address::~Address()
{
}
```

Comment: I don't see a member `address` for `Customer`. I only see a member *function*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I added those parameters thinking I'd make it a constructor, but that wasn't right either.  I changed it to just Address* address;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling

```
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Customer &customer) {
    input >> customer.custID >> customer.custName >> (*customer.address);
    return input;
}
```

this will call the extraction operator you defined in your `Address` class.

That being said, it may be a good idea to check that you are reading correctly in your operators.  I also am not sure why you are using a raw `Address` pointer.  You really should use a reference or a smart pointer.  Also for clarity/readability, I think it is usually good practice to put variable names in your function declarations as well as your definitions, even though it is not needed.

Comment: @kharvey you are trying to use `<<` on an `ifstream` to try an output an `endl`. Other than that, your code compiled once I removed the `endl`, as I did in my answer. I don't see anywhere you are misusing `>>`

Comment: Yes, found that error as well!  I have gotten a lot further and now am just trying to get it to read my file and output to Customer objects. Can't seem to get that part working yet, I may just have to post another question!